# Sequences and Bounds

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I'm having quite a problem with solving this. I already solved the first one (i) but I can't seem to properly write the explanation for the second. (ii). Not sure how to explain it with a random real number a.

1. Suppose real sequences ($s_n$) and ($t_n$) are bounded. (That is, that their ranges are bounded sets.) 
   i. Show the sequence given by ($s_n + t_n$) is bounded.
   ii. For any real number $a$, show that the sequence ($as_n$) is bounded.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: If $|s_n|\leq B$ for all $n$, then isn’t it clear that $|As_n|\leq |AB|$ for all $n$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(s_n), (t_n)$ bounded $ \Rightarrow (\exists N,M) (\forall n \in \mathbb{N}) |s_n| \leq N \land |t_n| \leq M$.
Therefore you have:
$$ |s_n + t_n| \leq |s_n| + |t_n| \leq N+M\ \ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$$
$$ |as_n| = |a| |s_n| \leq |a| N \ \ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \forall a \in \mathbb{R}$$

Hence $(s_n+t_n)$ and $(as_n)$ are bounded.

Comment: Thank you so much! Really helped!